# Retrieve JSON response from rxjava/retrofit POST request

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java, kotlin, retrofit2

I've created a POST request using rxjava and retrofit that successfully hits my backend server and logs the user in (I get a 201 response in my console, all good). However, I want to then retrieve the users access token that is returned, but when I try to access the rxjava result, it just gives me the object I passed to it. Nowhere can I find out how to get the json success response. I have also verified there is in fact a response in Postman, so it's something with how I make this call.

Here is my Retrofit portion

```
@Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
    @POST("api/v1/login")
    fun loginTask(@Body credentials: UserLogin)
            : Observable<UserLogin>
```

And the correspoinding API function

```
class ApiFunctions(val apiService: LunchVoteApi) {

    fun provideHello(): io.reactivex.Observable<Hello> {
        return apiService.helloMessage()
    }

    fun loginTask(email: String, password: String): io.reactivex.Observable<UserLogin> {
        val credentials: UserLogin = UserLogin(email, password)
        return apiService.loginTask(credentials)
    }
}
```

The UserLogin model that is deserialized by Gson

```
data class UserLogin(
    @SerializedName("email") val email: String,
    @SerializedName("password") val password: String
)
```

And finally the call in my LoginActivity

```
val loginTask = ApiProvider.provideLoginTask()
    override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Void): Boolean? {
        // TODO: attempt authentication against a network service.

        try {
            // Simulate network access.
            // Thread.sleep(2000)
            compositeDisposable.add(
                    loginTask.loginTask(mEmail, mPassword)
                            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                            .subscribe ({
                                result ->
                                    System.out.println(result.toString())
                            }, { error ->
                                System.out.println(error)
                            })
            )
        } catch (e: InterruptedException) {
            return false
        }
```

The confusion comes when I try to access the result -> portion of the compositeDisposable call. It just prints out the UserLogin object. Am I missing something here? Thanks.

Comment: It looks like the data you're passing in request and getting in response is of same type (`UserLogin`)....when you say "It just prints out the UserLogin object", do you mean it's printing same values as you provided in request?  Where are you expecting access token to be (should that be return type?)

Comment: @JohnO'Reilly Hi John. Yes it's printing out a UserLogin object in the result portion. The access token is of the format {accessToken: "token"} which I can see clearly in postman right now. So somehow I am not getting the JSON response I need.

Comment: In that case it looks like you have wrong return type in `fun loginTask(@Body credentials: UserLogin)  : Observable<UserLogin>`...return type should use pojo that has `accessToken` property)

Comment: @JohnO'Reilly ahhhh. Let me try that. Thanks

Comment: @JohnO'Reilly I'm having trouble determining where I would need to change the object from UserLogin to something with an accesstoken property. Would I change the retrofit function to be something like fun loginTask(@Body credentials: UserLogin)
            : Observable<AccessToken>? If so how do I provide the credentials to my server while also requiring an Accesstoken return type

Comment: The credentials are still supplied in `credentials` as before...this would just change return type.

Comment: @JohnO'Reilly great! That worked. I can now see the access token being printed. Thanks so much John

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was returning my UserLogin type instead of a pojo object with an access token property.

Changing my retrofit call to `@Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
    @POST("api/v1/login")
    fun loginTask(@Body credentials: UserLogin)
            : Observable<AccessToken>`

And creating a new model

`data class AccessToken(
        @SerializedName("accessToken") val email: String
)`

I am now able to print out the token. Thanks to @john-oreilly